# Sentence segmentation using nltk in big text files

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I need to use `nltk.sent_tokenize()` to extract sentences from big text files. Files size vary from 1MB to 400MB so it's not possible to load files entirely because of memory limits and I think it's not possible to use `nltk.sent_tokenize()` and read files line by line.

what do you suggest to do this task?

Comment: you could break the files into smaller chunks and process them at that grain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try just using the reader? The `nltk` corpus readers are designed to deliver text incrementally, reading large blocks from disk behind the scenes rather than entire files. So just open a `PlaintextCorpusReader` on your entire corpus, and it ought to deliver your entire corpus sentence by sentence without any shenanigans. For example:

```
reader = nltk.corpus.reader.PlaintextCorpusReader("path/to/corpus", r".*\.txt")
for sent in reader.sents():
    if "shenanigans" in sent:
        print(" ".join(sent))
```

Comment: I did not get it completely. May we ask in what context the word shenanigans is used or what it means? Can I supply as well a string with long text instead of a file?

Comment: Hi @TefoD, the OP's question is about how to get around memory limitations when dealing with large files. In this case no work-arounds ("shenanigans") are required, because the nltk will read the file in chunks-- and the reader will also handle tokenization behind the scenes. Regarding your question, I guess you are asking how to process a long string instead of a file: That's not the job of a corpus reader, so you'd start with `nltk.sent_tokenize()` and go on from there; but that's out of scope for this question, so please look elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks @alexis for taking time and ur detailled explanation. I just asked hence i went here from sent_tokenize() which works flawlessly but runs out of GPU memory on long strings :) Ur right of course, this is offtopic and I will look elsewhere..

Comment: ... and if you don't find anything, ask your own question about this (clarifying that it is about the long string running out of memory, not about how to process a string...)

Answer (score 0):

Stream the file and process it as you read through the file line by line.

If memory for storing the tokens is an issue then write the process tokens out line by line or in batches.

**Line by line:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from nltk import word_tokenize
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        tokenized_line = ' '.join(word_tokenize(line.strip()))
        print(tokenized_line, end='\n', file=fout)
```

**In batches (of 1000):**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from nltk import word_tokenize
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    processed_lines = []
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        tokenized_line = ' '.join(word_tokenize(line.strip()))
        processed_lines.append(tokenized_line)
        if i % 1000 = 0:
            print('\n'.join(processed_lines), end='\n', file=fout)
            processed_lines = []
```